g++-9 uses newer GLIBCXX symbols when linking against libstdc++
I am facing issues with g++ linking against newer GLIBCXX symbols for std::condition_variable::wait (with g++-9/g++-10/g++-11, libstdc++.so.6.0.30):
When using std::condition_variable::wait, GLIBCXX_3.4.30 symbols are referenced when linking against libstdc++.so.6.0.30 and GLIBCXX_3.4.11 symbols are referenced when linking against libstdc++.so.6.0.29.
Consider this minimal example:
// main.cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait(lck);
    return 0;
}


Compile with g++-9 main.cpp -o main
Check GLIBCXX symbol versions using strings main | grep GLIBCXX:

GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4
_ZSt9terminatev@GLIBCXX_3.4
_ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE@GLIBCXX_3.4.30
_ZSt20__throw_system_errori@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZNSt18condition_variableC1Ev@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZNSt18condition_variableD1Ev@GLIBCXX_3.4.11

As you can see, GLIBCXX_3.4.30 symbols are linked for std::condition_variable::wait even though g++-9 should not use these symbols and std::condition_variable::wait should be available for older versions.
When linking the same program against libstdc++.so.6.0.29, I get this output for strings main | grep GLIBCXX:
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZSt20__throw_system_errori@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZNSt18condition_variableC1Ev@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE@GLIBCXX_3.4.11
_ZNSt18condition_variableD1Ev@GLIBCXX_3.4.11

I can run this version on much older systems supporting GLIBCXX_3.4.11 (instead of GLIBCXX_3.4.30).
I am expecting that GLIBCXX_3.4.11 symbols are used when linking against libstdc++.so.6.0.30.
Am I wrong or is this something that should not happen?

why would you expect linking to a new library to use old symbols?

"I am expecting that GLIBCXX_3.4.11 symbols are used when linking against libstdc++.so.6.0.30" is there a reason why? Did  libstdc++ promise anything about ABI?

@PasserBy @AlanBirtles Mh, from the information on gcc.gnu.org ("Note, only symbols which are newly introduced will use the maximum version definition."), I expect that gcc-9 uses GLIBCXX_3.4.28 (or older) symbols when available in the libstdc++.so. did std::condition_variable::wait change?
But since I am wrong about this, can you explain, why this is not the case?

"did std::condition_variable::wait change?" yes, https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/03a810da10d8dfb5aec9261372cad7bf090e6986/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config/abi/pre/gnu.ver#L2460

"I expect that gcc-9 uses GLIBCXX_3.4.28 (or older) symbols when available in the libstdc++.so" - It will use the maximum version available in the libstdc++ library linked, for the symbol in question. Symbols only increment versions when they are added or change in some meaningful way. So condition_variable::wait changing in an ABI sense, means they introduce a new version for it, which means when you link against a libstdc++ containing that version, you get that version.
